# Returned React-Router <Route> doesn't work in switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wrote my application in a very modular way in the way that each package (section of the application) is a package and the only thing i'm returning from each package is a `<Route to="/dest" component="something" />`.

The problem that i'm having right now is that, this method of returning  are not really working in  and that's how i tested it:

The initial setup was something like this :

```
<Switch>
 <Dashboard {...rest} />
 <Users {...rest} />
 <Quiz {...rest} />
</Switch>
```

And the Dashboard component is something like this :

```
...
return (
    <Route exact path="/" render={ props => (
      <Dashboard {...props} {...stuff} />
    )}/>
  )
```

and almost the same thing for User and Quiz components, which are directly being imported from their module packages.

when i run the application, i can access `Dashboard` & `Users` but `Quiz` is not being rendered.
if i change the order and put quiz on top of `<Users />` it will work. which means it only can render one  after first exact route.

but instead, if i take all those code and write the Routes in the switch itself without referencing to another component, it works like a charm.

```
<Switch>
 <Route exact path="/" render={ props => (
  <div>demo</div>
 )}/>
 <Route path="/dashboard" render={ props => (
  <div>demo</div>
 )}/>
 <Route path="/users" render={ props => (
  <Users />
 )}/>
 <Route path="/quiz" component="Users"/>              
</Switch>
```

> I've tried both component, and render in route, this one is just a sample

any suggestion on why is this happening ?

**UPDATE 1**

I haven't managed to figure out what the problem is and what's causing it, but i found a way around it by creating a component that returns a `Switch` and direct `Routes` as children. then i exported the `Switch` to my main app.

Comment: You need `exact` on all of them

Comment: I tried, wasn't much of help, the problem isn't `exact` the problem is that importing routes from different components behave differently

Comment: have you tried `withRouter()` on your components?

Comment: What happens when you hit the /quiz route in the original scenario? if you add a noMatch Route at the bottom of  your switch does it render that instead?

Comment: @MichaelSorensen that's where things gets interesting, for some reason NoMatch explodes everything, if i add no match to the scenario without switch, no match will render with the component. but with switch no match doesn't even get rendered. it gets stuck like other components.

Comment: @Tony i'm testing it now.

Comment: Apparently <Switch> doesn't like imported routes. i might be wrong but that's what i'm getting. 
I've created a new component and put all the routes and switch there, and it's working. but still i have one extra component that i was trying to avoid.

Comment: I've never used the Router like this so I decided to give it a shot on my own. I made this fiddle and it looks like it works just fine? https://codepen.io/HappinessFactory/pen/zjzNLa Import "shouldn't" really make a difference. [Edit] Strike that. I got the same issue. Now I'm thinking that the Switch components only accepts Route components.

Comment: @MichaelSorensen then suppose it might be a bug. or as you mentioned the returned Routes are not Switch friendly .

Answer (score 3):

```
<Switch>
  <Dashboard {...rest} />
  <Users {...rest} />
  <Quiz {...rest} />
</Switch>
```

This will not work because [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) expects `Route`s to be direct children. It cannot perform its logic on arbitrary wrapper components.

I not sure if that would work but you would have to **directly** export Route from the module:

**Dashboard.js**

```
export default (
  <Route exact path="/" render={ props => (
    <Dashboard {...props} /> 
  )}/>
)
```

but when you do something like this:

```
export default (stuff) => (
  <Route exact path="/" render={ props => (
     <Dashboard {...props} {...stuff} />
  )}/>
)
```

Notice that you are not exporting a `Route` but a functional component that renders Route.

I personally think that you should only export purely components to be rendered without `Route`s and leave that up to library consumer.

Comment: Exporting the route as `export default ( ... )` is throwing error
`React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`